# IOS Keyboard GIF, crashing if number of GIF more than 5 due to memory

Tags: ios, swift3, keyboard, gif, custom-keyboard

I am downloading the GIF from the web service, saving the file name in sqlite and GIF in Document directory.

```
 for categories in arrcategpries
                    {
                        let dictCategory = categories as? NSDictionary


                        let str : String = (dictCategory?.value(forKey: "image") as! String)
                        var decodedString : String = ""
                        do
                        {
                            decodedString = try str.convertHtmlSymbols()!

                        }
                        catch{
                            decodedString = ""
                        }

                        print(decodedString)
                        let url : URL = URL(string: decodedString)! as URL
                        let path = URL.urlInDocumentsDirectory(with: "\(url.lastPathComponent)").path
                        let fileManager = FileManager()
                        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path)
                        {
                            print("File exists at destination url")
                            self.counter = self.counter+1
                            DispatchQueue.main.async
                                {

                                    self.progressView.setProgress(self.progressView.progress + self.progressIncrement, animated: true)

                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            self.counter = self.counter+1
                            DispatchQueue.main.async
                                {
                                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
                                    if let imageData = data {
                                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                                        self.saveImageToDocumentDirectory(with: url.lastPathComponent, image: image!)
                                    }
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

Here is how I am showing GIF. I am using https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif/tree/master/SwiftGifCommon.

```
     func showAllGifs(height : Float, width : Float) // view for gif
       {
      arrGifs = Model.getGIFDetails()
      for gif in arrGifs
    {
        let objGif = gif as! GIF


        let str : String = objGif.gifImage
        var decodedString : String = ""
        do
        {
            decodedString = try str.convertHtmlSymbols()!

        }
        catch{
            decodedString = ""
        }

        print(decodedString)
        let url : URL = URL(string: decodedString)! as URL
        let path = URL.urlInDocumentsDirectory(with: "\(url.lastPathComponent)").path
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path)
        {
            print("File exists at destination url")
        }
        else
        {
            //self.counter = self.counter+1
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url as URL)

                    if let imageData = data {


                        let fileManager = FileManager()
                        let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
                        fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
                    }
            }
        }

    }


    DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            var x : Int = 0
            for item in self.arrGifs
            {
                let gif : GIF = item as! GIF
                let gifName = URL(string: gif.gifImage)?.lastPathComponent
                // let ur
                let pathUrl = URL.urlInDocumentsDirectory(with: "\(gifName!)").path
                print((self.arrGifs.index(of: item)))
                x = (self.arrGifs.index(of: item) * 180)
                let y = 10
                let height = 170
                let width = 170
                let vwGif = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
                let imgGif : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
                let image = UIImage.gif(path: pathUrl) // 

                imgGif.image = image
                vwGif.addSubview(imgGif)
                let btngif : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
                btngif.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                btngif.tag = self.arrGifs.index(of: item)//gif.gifiId
                btngif.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnGifClick(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
                vwGif.addSubview(btngif)
                self.vwInnerScrollView.addSubview(vwGif)
            }
            self.widthConstraintGifScroll.constant = CGFloat(Double(x + 180))
    }
}
```

Working fine in Iphone 6 plus IOS 10, crahing in iphone 6 IOS 11 and Ipod and Ipad ,Both IOS 9
Need help.
Thank you.

Comment: The Keyboard extension crashes due to memory constraints.The only optimization you can do is make your Gif size smaller preferably 500KB or less as that is the size supported by iMessage extensions too.

Comment: My GIF are of size 100 - 150 kb. still crashing

Comment: can you share the crash logs?

Comment: No, It is working fine in simulator, but in case Ipad or Ipod, I cannot even debug. Keyboard just get dissapears. Is there any other way to display GIF in scrollview or cllectionview or webview

Comment: Yes, you can use UICollectionView to show gifs in cells having FLAnimatedImage objects.More info on FLANimatedImage at https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage